# Binary Tree Sets - Recursive Union

Tags: scala, recursion, set, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

So i am taking the scala course in coursera and I encountered something I cannot understand in a solution to the week 3 assignment regarding binary tree sets.
I was requested to write a union function recursively and the following is a working solution:

```
class Empty extends TweetSet:
    
  override def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet = that
    
  def incl(tweet: Tweet): TweetSet = NonEmpty(tweet, new Empty, new Empty)


class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet:

  override def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet =
    left.union(right.union(that)).incl(elem)
 
  def incl(x: Tweet): TweetSet =
    if x.text < elem.text then
      NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
    else if elem.text < x.text then
      NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
    else
      this
```

Initially I tried the following code for union function and it didn't terminate:

```
  override def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet =
    that.union(left.union(right)).incl(elem)
```

My question is - why?
I saw few examples and questions about this in previous threads, and I did managed to understand the first solution through step-by-step cases. But why do switching right\left with 'that' makes the program not terminate? (for clearance - swapping between left and right themselves changes nothing, only with 'that')

Thanks!

EDIT: Inputs are of reasonable size ofc.